# iPhotos disaster

Tags: photos, photos.app, sd-card, image-capture

I apparently had too many (3600) photos on my SD card to upload them via Image Capture so I used iPhoto. Upload went well but iPhoto erased my SD card.  I want to use to those photos outside of iPhoto but when I exported them to a Pictures folder it removed all the location data and dates DESPITE my instruction, on its inquiry, not to do that but to carry the ancillary data with the copied files.

Goal:  restore photos from iPhoto to SD card with original dates/location data, etc.  Once back to square 1, I'll figure out what other path to take, namely (I think), simply copying them copy-paste in Finder from the SD card to the Pictures folder.

Answer (score 1):

The erase of files from a SD card that contains photos is an easy engineering problem to solve.

Do not put any more files on that card and go get a copy of [Picture Rescue](https://www.prosofteng.com/picturerescue2/) to recover the deleted pictures.